# How to unconfigure Jekyll on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm working on a website hosted at [quinnmchugh.github.io](http://quinnmchugh.github.io/) and now whenever I push code to GitHub I receive an email from GitHub saying that

> The page build failed with the following error: unable to build page.
>   Please try again later. For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:
>    https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds

This website was copied from a template and I was unaware that Jekyll was baked into it. I don't want Jekyll to be enabled on this repo. How can I disable it and stop receiving emails from GitHub about build failures?

Answer (score 25):

You can add an empty **.nojekyll** file in the folder GitHub pages is serving. If serving from `/`, place it in your repo root; if serving from `/docs`, place it in `docs`; etc. This will instruct github pages to publish your files without processing them with jekyll.

Comment: I added a .nojekyll file to the root (see here https://github.com/QuinnMcHugh/quinnmchugh.github.io) and I still received a build failure email.

Comment: If jekyll is not the problem : your code is the problem. Check encoding. Try to remove all and add files one by one.

Comment: Added this file and no longer receives any build failure email, thanks!

Comment: GitHub should not parse the markdown if I'm disabling Jekyll. I just want to add files to GitHub.

Answer (score -4):

just **delete** the repository, create a **new one** add the **html** files you want to be hosted then create an new **branch** with the name **gh-pages**. that should stop the messages and have your site up and running.